# How can I safely mount a pull-up bar on a suspended stud wall?

Tags: framing, mounting

Wanted to install a pull-up bar in my room. I'm building it out of steel pipe. I want to attach the pipe to a wooden board, and mount the board on the wall. I feel like this would provide better support than without the board?

I'm unsure where would be the best spot to support the weight, since there aren't any long studs. (I weigh 150 lbs) Would the cripple studs or plates be able to support the load?

Similar questions have been answered already however, the wall I want to work on isn't attached to the floor.

In the photos the black line is where I would like the bar to be and the red indicates the same corner in each photo.

I'm new to this kind of thing, so any advice would be helpful!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your studs and framing should be fine. You need to screw into the existing studs and odds are that the pull up bar won't do a direct attachment very well connection bigger than the width of the stud. Also, the current framing layout will dictate where you place it.

Your idea of attaching a board to the wall and the pull up bar to it are a good one and what I would suggest even if you hadn't thought of it.

I would use a 2x6 or a 2x8 (the wider 2x8 might look better) and screw it to the studs with (3) #8 x 3-1/2" screws per stud to a minimum of (2) studs. Be sure that there is a stud on each side of each of the two pull up bar attachment points, which will likely require attaching the board to three studs. You might want to extend the board the full width of the opening for a better look.

How far out from the wall you place the bar has a significant affect on the force applied to the board, so keep it to 6" maximum.

Then attach the pull up bar per its instructions

Comment: It's difficult to tell how that floating wall is suspended. I'd expect drywall cracks with the dynamic loads at play here. Without the load compression and height most walls have there's more likely to be movement.

Comment: Ideally the floating walls have proper support beams run along their lower edge. We do not see any evidence of that in the photos so it is a big guess if they hang or are supported. If there are end to end beams across both of the right angle suspended areas showing in the OP's first picture the I would agree with @ Ack here. On the other hand if those walls are basically hanging from that triple plate at the top then I would echo the concern expressed by @isherwood.

Comment: I like the concerns that are being brought up. First, let me address that 'floating walls' is not at all a thing, at least in this context. A floating wall, if anything, is a non load bearing wall that allows for differential movement between the top and bottom. Even without the pictures, I full expect that this 'wall' does not have a beam at the bottom, just a plate. The top of the studs are end nailed w/ (2) 16d nails. Each have a minimum of about 70 lbs each. And the thing that not being considered is the shear strength of the dry wall and attachment.